# Ember Data - how to fetch data without using id

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm building an app using Ember and trying to talk to a back end API using Ember Data and writing custom adapters.

The API I am using is not RESTful or conform to JSONAPI standard. It has many endpoints that does not take in id but returns data for current user. 
For instance I have 'getAccountData' api that returns account data of the current user. The returned data has "id" associated with it (user_id of the current user) but you don't pass in "id" when calling the api to get the data.

I tried implementing **findRecord** method in my custom adapter but "id" parameter is required and it complains if I just call *this.get('store').findRecord('account-data')*. 
I can pass in dummy id like *this.get('store').findRecord('account-data', 1)* but this seems wrong since the 'id' of returned data won't be 1.

Should I be using **findAll** or **query** instead? is there a way to do this in clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `queryRecord`. From the [Ember docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_queryRecord):

> This method makes a request for one record, where the id is not known
>   beforehand (if the id is known, use findRecord instead).